# How to test my API Controller that accepts Protobuf as request body

Tags: .net, protocol-buffers

I have a controller that accepts a protobufs as the body. Now, I want to test the functionality(not unit testing) of my controller against a dummy .net console application. I am not able to figure out, how to go about it.

The code is as follows:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetData([FromBody] Request request)
    {
        Response response = new Response();

        if (request == null) {
            return BadRequest("Request is null");
        }

        //Do Something.
        return Ok(response);
    }
```

I also have a Custom input formatter:

```
public class CustomInputFormatter : InputFormatter
{
    public string ContentType { get; } = "application/protobuf";

    public override bool CanRead(InputFormatterContext context)
    {
        var requestContentType = context.HttpContext.Request.ContentType;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestContentType))
        {
            context.HttpContext.Request.ContentType = ContentType;
            return true;
        }
        else if (requestContentType.Contains(ContentType, System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public override async Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context)
    {
        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;

        if (request.ContentLength == 0)
        {
            return InputFormatterResult.Failure();
        }

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await request.Body.CopyToAsync(ms).ConfigureAwait(false);

            try
            {
                var req= Request.Parser.ParseFrom(ms.ToArray());
                return InputFormatterResult.Success(ms.ToArray());
            }
            catch (InvalidProtocolBufferException)
            {
                return InputFormatterResult.Failure();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I test the functionality of this Controller? The server is running at `https://localhost:8443/api/uriEndpoint`

Any pointers? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following client side code helped me to call the respective API:

```
        var request = new ProtoBufRequestObject();
        // Populate your request object as needed
        using var stream = new MemoryStream();
        request.WriteTo(stream);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        try
        {
            var r = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                Method = HttpMethod.Post,
                RequestUri = new Uri(RequestEndpoint),
                Content = new StreamContent(stream),

            };
            var response = await client.SendAsync(r).ConfigureAwait(false);
            Assert.IsTrue(response.IsSuccessStatusCode);
            var config = ProtoBufResponseObject.Parser.ParseFrom(response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult());

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Do something
        }
```

Other than this, you would also want to check a few things:

- Make sure in your `CustomInputFormatter`, the over-ridden `CanRead` returns `true` for your request.
- Register your `CustomInputFormatter` in the `Startup.cs` file in `services.AddMvc` block.